# RNDC: Connection Refused

Tags: vps, bind, reverse-dns

Just got myself a new VPS, not the first I can assure you.

Upon adding any DNS entry, I am prompted with this:

```
WARNING: key file (/etc/rndc.key) exists, but using default configuration file (/etc/rndc.conf)
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

I have no idea how this problem started, and I've tried the cPanel `fixrdnc` script with no success.

What's the trick to get this warning to go away?

Answer (score 0):

If it is CentOS6 then you can just delete rndc.key and restart named. That fixed similar issue I had some time ago.

Comment: Nope, Didn't work. Still getting the same error.